# Cannot make sense of a derivative

Tags: calculus, derivatives

**Short version of the question:**

In this presentation http://www.slideshare.net/ShangxuanZhang/xgboost (page 74-75)I cannot understand how the gradient of the L function is calculated.
$$
L = y_i  \log  {{1}\over{1+e^{-\hat{y}_i}}}+(1-y_i)\log {{e^{-\hat{y}_i}}\over{1+e^{-\hat{y}_i}}}
$$

On page 75 it reports that

$$
\textrm{grad} = {{1}\over{1+e^{-\hat{y}_i}}}-y_i
$$

But I have not been ale to reproduce the passages to get to that result. Please note that on page 73 is specified that the gradient is intended with respect to $ y_i $ , but I suspect that it should be calculated with respect to $ \hat{y}_i $, because first it makes sense in the context, second in the whole presentation and in the paper that presents this method, gradients are always calculated with respect to $ \hat{y}_i $.

Either way I cannot understand how he obtain that result.

**Long version of the question:**

I am trying to use the xgboost R package for a little side project. One of the reasons that have lead me to try it out is the fact that it lets you define your own  customized objective function. Problem is that the example I reported above is pretty much the most detailed documentation that I were able to find. In the official documentation (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xgboost/xgboost.pdf, page 9)uses the same example and explains that you should define a function that returns gradient and second order gradient and just input it as a parameter of the training method. Making such a function wouldn't be a problem if only I were sure about what "gradient and second order gradient" means, and I am not sure since I cannot understand the only example I have, which is supposed to be quite simple, so if somone can explain me what calculations he permorms that would be much appreciated.

Comment: @callculus Sorry I couldn't accept your answer right away, I just had to sit down at a table and go through each of the passages you explained so well, which I have been only just able to do. I can assure you that your help have been indeed much appreciated, thank you ^^

Comment: In this case I have to excuse myself. If you have any question about the answer or the derivative feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

$L = y_i  log  {{1}\over{1+e^{-\hat{y}_i}}}-y_ilog {{e^{-\hat{y}_i}}\over{1+e^{-\hat{y}_i}}}+log {{e^{-\hat{y}_i}}\over{1+e^{-\hat{y}_i}}}$

First notice that

$-log {{e^{-\hat{y}_i}}\over{1+e^{-\hat{y}_i}}}=log {{1+e^{-\hat{y}_i}}\over{e^{-\hat{y}_i}}}$

$L = y_i  log  {{1}\over{1+e^{-\hat{y}_i}}}+y_ilog {{1+e^{-\hat{y}_i}}\over{e^{-\hat{y}_i}}}+log {{e^{-\hat{y}_i}}\over{1+e^{-\hat{y}_i}}}$

One logarithm rule is $log(a)+log(b)=log(ab)$. ${1+e^{-\hat{y}_i}}$ can be cancelled out.

$L = y_ilog {{1}\over{e^{-\hat{y}_i}}}+log {{e^{-\hat{y}_i}}\over{1+e^{-\hat{y}_i}}}$

$L = y_ilog ({{e^{\hat{y}_i}}})+log {{e^{-\hat{y}_i}}\over{1+e^{-\hat{y}_i}}}$

$L = y_i\hat{y_i}+log {{e^{-\hat{y}_i}}\over{1+e^{-\hat{y}_i}}}$

$L = y_i\hat{y_i}+log {{e^{-\hat{y}_i}}}-log(1+e^{-\hat{y}_i})$

$L = y_i\hat{y_i}-\hat y_i-log(1+e^{-\hat{y}_i})$

Now you can differentiate w.r.t $\hat{y_i}$. For the last summand you have to apply the chain rule. The result is the given result multiplied by (-1).